# how do i use tablesorter to work with 4 row groups

Tags: jquery, grouping, tablesorter

I have a table that has 3 rows per record and a blank row following that. I want to consider those 4 rows as a single row when sorting using the tablesorter plugin. Please help!!!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, that [mod of tablesorter](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm) was added to [tablesorter v2.0.5](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). I've documented [how to use the `ccsChildRow` option](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#cssChildRow) on my blog.

Also, if you are interested, I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) on [github](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) which has a lot of enhancements and useful widgets :)

Answer (score 1):

For v2.4 and above there is a new css class name to use. Just add the class "tablesorter-childRow" to your child rows. See [here](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html) for a detailed example.